# Convert meters to decimal

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, coordinates

I have the following coordinates in meters for UTM 34S / Datum WGS-84:

Lat.: 311965;
Long.: 8695153;

How do I convert these coordinates into decimal degrees or DMS?

Comment: We don't have enough information to answer your question. What coordinate system are your coordinates in? I'm guessing a particular UTM Zone? What do you want to convert to? Decimal degrees?

Comment: We would also need to know what software you have available to perform the coordinate transformation... the instructions vary depending on software. To successfully convert metres (projected) to geographic DD (Decimal Degrees) or DMS (Degrees Minutes Seconds) you need to specify the projected coordinate system the XY is in and the geographic coordinate system you want the output to be in. Assuming *any* of these parameters is dangerous! Is there metadata for the records? Given the numbers are too big they are not Lat/Lon, more likely Easting/Northing.

Comment: I need to add each coordinate to a shapefile (point) in QGIS. I do not have any software that allows me to convert meters to DMS or Decimal (perhaps QGIS can do it). I do not have any metadata for the records.

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question per question.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in a dodgy way by using a form like this: https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/utm-latitude-longitude-d_1370.html

This one looks a little more robust: http://franzpc.com/apps/coordinate-converter-utm-to-geographic-latitude-longitude.html

But as the comments suggest, to do it properly, you really need to know what datum you're on, and you've only provided info on your projection. You can get something that should be ok by assuming you're on the WGS84 datum, and your lat/lon will then be on that too. To do it right, you should use the right datum, though!

Comment: Alex, thank you. I think I will be abble to solve it using the second link you posted.